# Editor does not contain a main type - messed up Build path config

Tags: java, eclipse, sql-server-2008

Does anyone know of any complete guide that shows how to reconfigure from scratch the "Build Path" in Eclipse?
In the attempt to add a .jar file I messed up the current configuration. Or if you think volunteering pictures of your Eclipse config screen may help, that would be appreciated it too!

I hope I will not have to reinstall Eclipse.

The error I keep getting (for any classes, also those who used to run perfectly) is: "Editor does not contain a main type." (BEFORE any program even LAUNCHES).

I had deleted JRE but then I put JRE back by right clicking the root of "package explorer" - Build path - Add libraries - JRE System Library. Still same error.

Answer (score 1):

The "Build Path" -> "Configure Build Path" tool can be used to fix a lot of problems that other build path modifying techniques can cause.

Open that tool and look through the tabs and see if you can find the entry that is causing the problem.  Pay special attention to the Libraries tab.  You may just want to remove all the entries in this tab and re-add the ones you need one by one.  Build path problems are often broken entries in this tab.

You might also try looking through "Run" -> "Run Configurations" tool and remove any run configurations associated with the project.

Comment: Dan, I precisely don't know what to change in the "Configure build path" tool! I've been there countless times today (just got acquainted to it), it has many tabs and options. I would like to know how to restore it to its default functional options. As for the "Run Configurations" tool, it doesn't appear in my "Run" menu at all. Thanks!

Comment: I guess I would need to know more about what caused the problem then.  Also: you have no Run Configurations tool?  You definitely should have it.  Are you using some exotic version of Eclipse?

Comment: I added some detail to my answer.  The tab you should look at is the libraries tab.

Comment: I know "library" is important, but don't know what it should look like. sqljdbc4.jar and JRE system library is what I have there currently, in this order - in case the order matters. What should I have there? I still get the same error.

Comment: That sounds about right.  The order is not the issue.  Try removing that jar and adding it again, using the tool.

Comment: You can also creating a new project and copying all your source files to the new project.  Then, the build path will be empty, and you can add what you need (just sqljdbc4.jar, I guess).  That is easier than reinstalling eclipse.  I am shooting in the dark here, but I think that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any source folder added in the Build path configuration. I just went to Build Path configuration and added the folder in the "Source" panel. (I had previously deleted it by mistake.)
This solved my problem, now my applets and console classes run perfectly like they used to.

http://zenverse.net/editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type-error-in-eclipse/